# Detecting different types of Events using Drools Fusion?

Tags: events, drools, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

I’m a bit new to Drools; Although, I have been reading the docs on Drools Fusion (Complex Event Processing), which states in [Section 2.3](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Beta1/drools-fusion-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e492):

> *"The streams can be provided to the application in various forms, from JMS queues to flat text files, from database tables to raw
>   sockets or even through web service calls.”*

My questions are, could fusion be used to detect the following types of events, and if so, could you supply a small example of what the syntax would look like:

- Detecting events from RSS/Atom feeds (so, anytime a new feed arrives, it can fire some rule);
- It mentions *“service calls”*, could perhaps Fusion be used to poll some web-service to check for changes. For example, say a certain web-service offers a GET for reading comments. However, I would want to have a kind-of *simulated PuSH*, where if there is a new comment, I could treat it as an event.